# XSLT how to merge based on an element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the below input XML:

```
<Fees>
<user>
    <value>userA</value>
</user>
<feeList>
    <userFee>
        <owner>
            <Id>owner1</Id>
        </owner>
        <Amount>
            <sum>100</sum>
        </Amount>
    </userFee>
    <userFee>
        <owner>
            <Id>owner1</Id>
        </owner>
        <Amount>
            <sum>100</sum>
        </Amount>
    </userFee>
    <userFee>
        <owner>
            <Id>owner2</Id>
        </owner>
        <Amount>
            <sum>100</sum>
        </Amount>
    </userFee>
    <userFee>
        <owner>
            <Id>owner3</Id>
        </owner>
        <Amount>
            <sum>100</sum>
        </Amount>
    </userFee>
</feeList>
<user>
    <value>userB</value>
</user>    
<feeList>
    <userFee>
        <owner>
            <Id>owner1</Id>
        </owner>
        <Amount>
            <sum>120</sum>
        </Amount>
    </userFee>
    <userFee>
        <owner>
            <Id>owner2</Id>
        </owner>
        <Amount>
            <sum>100</sum>
        </Amount>
    </userFee>
    <userFee>
        <owner>
            <Id>owner3</Id>
        </owner>
        <Amount>
            <sum>180</sum>
        </Amount>
    </userFee>
    <userFee>
        <owner>
            <Id>owner3</Id>
        </owner>
        <Amount>
            <sum>100</sum>
        </Amount>
    </userFee>
    <userFee>
        <owner>
            <Id>owner4</Id>
        </owner>
        <Amount>
            <sum>75</sum>
        </Amount>
    </userFee>
    <userFee>
        <owner>
            <Id>owner4</Id>
        </owner>
        <Amount>
            <sum>25</sum>
        </Amount>
    </userFee>
</feeList>
```

There are 4 `userFee` elements in the `feeList`. Two of them belong to the same owner "owner1" and these needs to be merged as 1 and 2 of them belog to different owners. I need the following output:

```
user: userA    
Total sum: 400
count: 3 (basically no. of unique owner id's for the user fee
    owner and amount: owner1, 200 (Note there are 2 owner1 elements, and they need to be merged into one row with their sum)   
    owner and amount: owner2, 100
    owner and amount: owner3, 100
```

So far I have the following XSLT:
(...I am still struggling with group and merging them.)

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Fees">
   user: <xsl:value-of select="user/value"/>
      <!-- how to get count of unique userFee by owner ID -->
   Count:<xsl:value-of select="count(feeList/userFee)"/>
   Total Sum:<xsl:value-of select="sum(feeList/userFee/amount/sum)"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="feeList/userFee">
         <!-- how to group same owner into one and sum there amount -->
     owner and amount: <xsl:value-of select="owner/Id"/>, <xsl:value-of select="amount/sum"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately Limited to XSLT 1.0.
Thank you

Comment: Are you really limited to XSLT-1.0? Or can you use higher versions?

Comment: @zx485 Unfortunately limited to XSLT-1.0

Comment: This is a basic grouping task. There are countless answers on SO that show how to do grouping in XSLT 1.0. Search for Muenchian Grouping, you will get more examples that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean, i want the count to be 3. Count of 1 per each owner. Also, I
>   am running into issue when i have more than one `<feeList>`. In the
>   example i have only gave one  but actually there can be many.
>   `<feeList>` is one per user and i have multiple user in the actual
>   file. I think the issue is with the `<xsl:key name="overall" match="userFee" use="owner/Id" />` looking in the whole file. Can i
>   make this key just look into each `<feeList>` element?

Based on this comment on the other answer, it sounds to me like you need to use a composite key using the both the owner/ID and also the user/value.

It would be much easier to tell for certain if you updated your question with an example that contains more than one `user` and corresponding `feeList`.

Also, to get a count of the number of owners per user you can create a variable that outputs a string character for each owner. The length of the string will be the number of owners. There's probably a much better way to do this, but it's not coming to mind right now.

Full example...

**XML Input** (updated to have more than one `user` and `feeList`)

```
<Fees>
    <user>
        <value>userA</value>
    </user>
    <feeList>
        <userFee>
            <owner>
                <Id>owner1</Id>
            </owner>
            <Amount>
                <sum>100</sum>
            </Amount>
        </userFee>
        <userFee>
            <owner>
                <Id>owner1</Id>
            </owner>
            <Amount>
                <sum>100</sum>
            </Amount>
        </userFee>
        <userFee>
            <owner>
                <Id>owner2</Id>
            </owner>
            <Amount>
                <sum>100</sum>
            </Amount>
        </userFee>
        <userFee>
            <owner>
                <Id>owner3</Id>
            </owner>
            <Amount>
                <sum>100</sum>
            </Amount>
        </userFee>
    </feeList>
    <user>
        <value>userB</value>
    </user>    
    <feeList>
        <userFee>
            <owner>
                <Id>owner1</Id>
            </owner>
            <Amount>
                <sum>120</sum>
            </Amount>
        </userFee>
        <userFee>
            <owner>
                <Id>owner2</Id>
            </owner>
            <Amount>
                <sum>100</sum>
            </Amount>
        </userFee>
        <userFee>
            <owner>
                <Id>owner3</Id>
            </owner>
            <Amount>
                <sum>180</sum>
            </Amount>
        </userFee>
        <userFee>
            <owner>
                <Id>owner3</Id>
            </owner>
            <Amount>
                <sum>100</sum>
            </Amount>
        </userFee>
        <userFee>
            <owner>
                <Id>owner4</Id>
            </owner>
            <Amount>
                <sum>75</sum>
            </Amount>
        </userFee>
        <userFee>
            <owner>
                <Id>owner4</Id>
            </owner>
            <Amount>
                <sum>25</sum>
            </Amount>
        </userFee>
    </feeList>
</Fees>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="user_fees" match="userFee" use="concat(../preceding-sibling::user[1]/value,'~',owner/Id)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each select="feeList">
      <xsl:variable name="totalOwners">
        <xsl:for-each select="userFee[count(.|key('user_fees',concat(../preceding-sibling::user[1]/value,'~',owner/Id))[1])=1]">
          <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1"><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('User: ',preceding-sibling::user[1]/value,'&#xA;')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('Total Sum: ',sum(userFee/Amount/sum),'&#xA;')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('Count: ', string-length($totalOwners), '&#xA;')"/>
      <xsl:for-each 
        select="userFee[count(.|key('user_fees',concat(../preceding-sibling::user[1]/value,'~',owner/Id))[1])=1]">
        <xsl:value-of 
          select="concat('&#x9;owner and amount: ',
          owner/Id,
          ', ',
          sum(key('user_fees',concat(../preceding-sibling::user[1]/value,'~',owner/Id))/Amount/sum),'&#xA;')"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
User: userA
Total Sum: 400
Count: 3
    owner and amount: owner1, 200
    owner and amount: owner2, 100
    owner and amount: owner3, 100

User: userB
Total Sum: 600
Count: 4
    owner and amount: owner1, 120
    owner and amount: owner2, 100
    owner and amount: owner3, 280
    owner and amount: owner4, 100
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQ8

Comment: Thank you so much @Daniel Haley. Exactly what i needed. I updated the input in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is, as Tomalak mentioned, a task for [Muenchian Grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/muenchian-grouping). Under this tag you will find a lot of examples of how to use it. In the beginning it can be a bit tricky to use and because of that XSLT-2.0 introduced the much simpler `xsl:for-each-group` for this kind of task.

However, here is one solution applying this method:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="overall" match="userFee" use="owner/Id" />   <!-- key required for Muenchian method -->

  <xsl:template match="/Fees">
    User: <xsl:value-of select="user/value"/>
    <!-- iterate over unique owners - Muenchian method -->
    <xsl:for-each select="feeList/userFee[generate-id() = generate-id(key('overall',owner/Id)[1])]">
      Owner:<xsl:value-of select="owner/Id"/>
      <!-- how to get count of unique userFee by owner ID -->
      Count:<xsl:value-of select="count(key('overall',owner/Id))"/>
      <!-- how to sum the amount of one owner -->
      Total Sum:<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('overall',owner/Id)/Amount/sum)"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    Total count: <xsl:value-of select="count(feeList/userFee)" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output is:**

```
User: userA
Owner:owner1
Count:2
Total Sum:200

Owner:owner2
Count:1
Total Sum:100

Owner:owner3
Count:1
Total Sum:100

Total count: 4
```

Comment: Thank you so much @zx485. One quick question, how do i get Total count here? Since owner1 is repeated twice, i want total count as "3" rather than 4(<xsl:value-of select="count(feeList/userFee)"/>). Since the variable are mutable in xslt, i cant use a counter in the for loop as weel

Comment: I added a `Total count` output to the answer. The value is `4 = 2*owner1 + 1*owner2 + 1*owner3`. There are only two `owner1` entries in the given XML. AND: `xsl:variable`s are **not mutable** - just like in many other functional languages.

Comment: I mean, i want the count to be 3. Count of 1 per each owner.  Also, I am running into issue when i have more than one <feeList>. In the example i have only gave one <feeList> but actually there can be many. <feeList> is one per user and i have multiple user in the actual file.  I think the issue is with the <xsl:key name="overall" match="userFee" use="owner/Id" /> looking in the whole file. Can i make this key just look into each <feeList> element?

Comment: Thanks @zx485 . I would need to group by owner/Id for each User. The owner/ID might be repeated for a different user and that is fine, but if the owner is repeated for the same user then only i want it to be grouped.